# Dynamically copying a set of forms inside a div

Tags: jquery, html

I am building a invoice web application and need som help. I have a set of forms where the user can add a order when creating a new invoice. Below is a image.

[image]

I want to give the user to be able to add as many orders he/she likes. When the user clicks a button named "add more" I want a copy of the div containg the forms to appear below the current.

What is the best way of doing this? Are there any avaible plugins for this type of tasks?

Comment: Jquery in-build method [`clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/).

Answer (score 1):

Write a copy of that div in the html and add the hidden class to it. When you need to add a copy, `.clone()` that hidden div, append it to the form, and `.show()` it. The reason to have the hidden div is to ensure that the input values are empty when copied.

Example:

```
var $copy = $("#hidden-div").clone();
$("#your-form").append($copy);
$copy.show()
```